# Finding Elements with multiple namespaces

Tags: xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am having troubles finding elements in an Xml file using LINQ to XML in C# 4.0.

Here is the simplified Xml Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mDoc xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/taxonomy/2003/1">
    <content>
        <gdsPage xmlns="http://mysite.com/schemas/gdsPage/1/">
            <textContainer id="C_134572">
                <text id="T_399231">Content</text>
                <text id="T_399232">Content</text>
            </textContainer>
            <textContainer id="C_134607" brands="PRMR " did="1" renderOption="" needceiling="0">
                <text id="T_399268">Content</text>
            </textContainer>
        </gdsPage>
    </content>
</mDoc>
```

Please note the two seperate namespaces defined in this doc.

I define them in my code as follows:

```
XNamespace ns_mdoc = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/taxonomy/2003/1";
XNamespace ns_gds = "http://mysite.com/schemas/gdsPage/1/";
```

Then from what I understand, I should be able to prepend the namespace onto an element to find it, like so:

```
var query =
                from links in
                    xdoc.Element(ns_gds + "linkContainer").Elements("link")
                where links.Attribute("id").Value == "C_134608" || links.Attribute("id").Value == "L_233140"
                select links;
```

This returns null. I tried many other combinations of accessors like Axis search and Descendants:

```
var stuff = from links in xdoc.Descendants(ns_gds + "linkContainer")
                        select new {
                            link = links.Element(ns_gds + "link").Value
                        };
```

I also tried using both names spaces, one then the other. Still Null.

What am I missing here?

Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems here:

1. Your XML does not contain any
   `linkContainer` or `link` elements -
   they are named `textContainer` and
   `text`.
2. Also you have to use `Descendands()`
   and not `Elements()` if the child
   nodes you want to access are not
   direct children.
3. You have to set the namespace on all
   elements in your query that are
   under that namespace - you are
   missing the namespace currently on
   the `Elements("link")` part.

With this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mDoc xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/taxonomy/2003/1">
  <content>
    <gdsPage xmlns="http://mysite.com/schemas/gdsPage/1/">
      <textContainer id="C_134572">
        <text id="T_399231">Content</text>
        <text id="T_399232">Content</text>
      </textContainer>
      <textContainer id="C_134607" brands="PRMR " did="1" renderOption="" needceiling="0">
        <text id="T_399268">Content</text>
      </textContainer>
    </gdsPage>
  </content>
</mDoc>
```

this works for me:

```
var query =  from links in xdoc.Descendants(ns_gds + "textContainer")
                               .Elements(ns_gds + "text")
             where links.Attribute("id").Value == "T_399268" ||
                   links.Attribute("id").Value == "L_233140"
             select links;
```